# Break an array into separate chunks

Tags: c, structure, typedef

I need to create a C program (I'm using Xcode) that reads a file and separates the first line into 4 different variables.

I have a typedef structure called "network":

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b, c, d;
    char op_sys[10];
} network;
```

I also have a file that contains a list of IP addresses alongside their operating system.
For example, the first lines reads: 192.116.112.1 windows

I want to scan this first line and make:

```
a = 192
b = 116
c = 112
d = 1
op_sys = "windows"
```

And then move on to the next line and do the same..

Any idea how to do that? Any advice would be great!!!

I'm trying this step by step right now. It's reading the file and printing it, I just don't know how to separate it into separate variables.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *input;
    char s[25];

    input = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(s, 25, input) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: show us some code you've tried and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: I just edited my original question to add what I'm stuck on now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple implementation:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10 // Max length (including NULL character at the end) of op_sys field

typedef struct {
   int a, b, c, d;
   char op_sys[SIZE];
} network;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *input;
    char s[16+SIZE+1];  // This will contain a line from the text file. (16+SIZE+1) is the max length possible for a line.
                        // 16 for IP address, SIZE for the OS name and 1 for the NULL character.
    network net;
    char *token=NULL;
    char delim[]={'.',' ','\n','\0'};   // Delimiters used to divide each line in tokens

    input = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(s,(16+SIZE+1),input)!=NULL)
    {
      token=strtok(s,delim);        // We get the first octet of the address
      net.a=atoi(token);
      token=strtok(NULL,delim);     // We get the second octet of the address
      net.b=atoi(token);
      token=strtok(NULL,delim);     // We get the third octet of the address
      net.c=atoi(token);
      token=strtok(NULL,delim);     // We get the fourth octet of the address
      net.d=atoi(token);
      token=strtok(NULL,delim);     // We get the OS name...
      char *ptr=net.op_sys;
      ptr=strncpy(ptr,token,SIZE);  // ... and we copy it in net.op_sys
      ptr[SIZE-1]='\0';
      printf("%3d.%3d.%3d.%3d\t\t%s\n",net.a,net.b,net.c,net.d,net.op_sys);     // We print the values of all the fields
    }

    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Remember that this implementation doesn't check if the format of the lines is correct or not, nor it checks if the length of the OS name is longer than SIZE. I leave that kind of check to you.

Comment: This might be a basic concept I'm not understanding, but why is the argument of the first strtok() function (s,delim) while the others are (NULL,delim) ?? This function is fairly new to me, I haven't used it much. Do the arguments basically mean it will read and store the string until it reaches a delimiter ("." " " "\n" "\0"), save that, and then start again from that point to the next delimiter? Why does it start from null? I hope that makes sense..

Comment: It's just the way strtok works. The first call to the function takes the string you want to split as the first argument and the sequence of delimeters as the second argument. This first call will return the first token (if a delimeter is found) or NULL. Then if you want to get another token you call the function again but with NULL as the first argument; that basically means try to get another token starting from the position right after the end of the last token. Obviously the second call will return another token (if a delimeter is found) or NULL...

Comment: .. And so on, you can keep calling the function as many times you want. Remember that you usually should check the return value of strtok but in your example, as I wrote in the answer above, this check is not implemented because it is assumed that the format of the text file is correct.